# How to get the int64 size of an image as a string?

Tags: go

I have a image file stored in the resource folder.I am opening it and I am able to get its size but when I am printing it in string using string(size) it is showing special character(a square).I checked its type using reflect.Typeof(),it is giving int64.How to convert this to string and print the size as a string????

I am using the following code:

```
    imgFile,_ := os.Open("QrImgGA.png")
    fInfo, _ := imgFile.Stat()
    var size int64 = fInfo.Size()
    fmt.Println(string(size))//Prints the size correctl.Eg.,678899
```

But when I try to put it in json it shows some special character by doing the following:

```
    m:=make(map[string]string)
    m["bytes"]=string(size)
    js,_:=json.Marshal(m)
    fmt.Println(string(js))//Gives value as special character
```

Any suggestions?? or is there some another way of finding the size of an image???

Comment: Are you abe to create an example recreating your issue on play.golang.org ?

Comment: Want to show us some code?

Comment: You're asking how to get the size, but then you say "I am able to get its size". Try creating a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Package strconv](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/)
>
> ```
> import "strconv"
> ```
>
> [func FormatInt](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#FormatInt)
>
> `func FormatInt(i int64, base int) string`
>
> FormatInt returns the string representation of i in the given base,
>   for 2 <= base <= 36. The result uses the lower-case letters 'a' to 'z'
>   for digit values >= 10.

---

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    size := int64(678899)
    str := strconv.FormatInt(size, 10)
    fmt.Println(str)
}
```

Output:

```
678899
```